# What is a good fast CD Audio Ripper for my Lubuntu System?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, cd, disk-ripping

I have a Lubuntu OS laptop and was wondering what the best CD Audio Ripping Program was? I need the name of the program ASAP! As soon as possible please!

Comment: what is a "CR"?

Comment: I meant to say CD.

Comment: Then I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Audacity! I am just cutting the audio I want. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

regarding audacity, [it's not a ripping tool.](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/play.html)

Depending on what version of Lubuntu you're using, Asunder is a choice.

I know it's an old thread, but it still high on search engines